# Symmetric groups of Hexagonal tiling

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

[image]

Determine the symmetric group G of this infinite hexagonal tiling $\varGamma$. i.e. G={g$\in$ G｜g$\varGamma$=$\varGamma$}.
What I know is that G is generated by certain rotations, reflexions and translations. And the rotations and reflexions part is the dihedral group of order 6 $D_{6}$. If I choose the natural basis $e_{1}=(1,0)$ and $e_{2}=(0,1)$ of $R^{2}$, then $D_{6}$ is generated by R=\begin{pmatrix}
cos(π/3) & -sin(π/3) \\
sin(π/3) & cos(π/3)
\end{pmatrix}
and S=\begin{pmatrix}
cos(π/3) & sin(π/3) \\
sin(π/3) & -cos(π/3)
\end{pmatrix}
And I am down to the translation part T which is generated by $T_{i}$ which is translation by ($x_{i}$,$y_{i}$)
Where ($x_{i}$,$y_{i}$) could be ($3/2,\sqrt 3/2$) and ($-3/2,\sqrt 3/2$) and ($0,-\sqrt 3/2$).But I don't know how to represent $T_{i}$ in matrix form. Any help?
Then I Can write G=〈$R$,$S$,$T_{1}$,$T_{2}$,$T_{3}$〉
Am I right? Or did I miss something? Many Thanks!

Comment: Translations are not linear, so you will not be representing them by $2\times2$ matrices. Instead you can canonically embed the affine group ${\rm Aff}_2\Bbb R$ as block-upper triangular matrices in $GL_3\Bbb R$ with lower right corner $1$. The exercise doesn't seem to explicitly ask you for a matrix representation, however. So you can avoid this by identifying your lattice of translations with $\Bbb Z^2$ (group-theoretically), determining how $D_6$ acts on it, then the symmetry group is the semidirect product $\Bbb Z^2\rtimes D_6$.

Comment: @runway44 Thanks! But why is the lattice of translations can  be identified as $Z^{2}$?

Comment: You can pick two generators that are $\Bbb Z$-linearly independent. Look at the centers of the hexagons, pick three adjacent hexagon centers, use one as the origin and the other two for displacement vectors to translate by.